# mechanize raises BrowserStateError

Tags: python, mechanize

I have the following code:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br._factory.is_html = True
br.form = mechanize._form.ParseString('<form method="post"</form>', 'http://localhost/post.php')[1]

br.form.new_control('text', 'test',{'value':'something'})
br.form.fixup()
br.submit()
```

The code works sometimes but other times it raises BrowserStateError: not viewing HTML. Am I not overriding _factory.is_html correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `mechanize` requires you to have an actual response in order to submit the form:

```
def viewing_html(self):
    """Return whether the current response contains HTML data."""
    if self._response is None:
        raise BrowserStateError("not viewing any document")
    return self._factory.is_html
```

([mechanize/_mechanize.py, line 440](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/_mechanize.py#L440))